# Gitlab: While cloning a repo via ssh it keeps asking for password

Tags: linux, git, gitlab

I have installed gitlab on LINUX(RHEL 6.7). While cloning the repo via ssh it keeps asking for the password for git, however it is working fine by using http:

```
$ git clone http://MGJV67@il06epclin1.am.mot-solutions.com/MGJV67/NewPROJ.git
Cloning into 'NewPROJ'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

mgjv67@mgjv67-430 MINGW64 /c/TCS/Gitlab/NewPROJ (master)
$ git clone git@il06epclin1.am.mot-solutions.com:MGJV67/NewPROJ.git
Cloning into 'NewPROJ'...
git@il06epclin1.am.mot-solutions.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can clone anonymously over http, you can only clone over SSH with a valid SSH identity.
Create an SSH key and add the public key to your Gitlab user account, or add it as a deploy key for your project in case you only need read-only access.

Comment: I have uploaded the ssh key as well but still it is asking for password.